# DSR is on. Don't send DTR on Android

Tags: android

In the logcat I'm seeing this a lot

> "DSR is on. Don't send DTR on Android".

I have tethered my phone wirelessly to my mac because my internet is down. I have it in dev mode also. So what does that mean? I have seen something about bluetooth but it's off though.

DSR? DTR?

Comment: I got it on i9100 running Android4.
What device and OS do you use?

Comment: I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 running 4.0.3

Comment: I have the same error, repeating a LOT and cluttering up my logcat. SGS2/4.0.3.

Comment: I assume it's something Samsung's *brilliant* programmers added. I also have a Galaxy S2.

Comment: same thing s2 running MIUI flavor of ICS 4.0.3

Answer (score 3):

**DSR** = Data Set Ready
**DTR** = Data Terminal Ready

`<nostalgia>`These are (hardware) flow control signals that are used for serial communications between devices like printers, modems, etc.`</nostalgia>`.

Since your tethering is via USB I'm guessing that there is some kind of USB serial port emulator that is running that may be generating these log messages. But that's just a guess.